# TLSv1_2 (TLS1.2) support in PJSIP library

Tags: android, ios, ssl, openssl, pjsip

I am using latest [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) library in my Android/iOS applications. I want use TLSv1.2 connection in my project. Which TLS version does PJSIP support? From source code it seems to be supporting TLSv1.0. Is there a way to add TLSv1_2 support to PJSIP library?

Answer (score 1):

> I want use TLSv1.2 connection in my project. Which TLS version does PJSIP support?

From [Configuring PJSIP with TLS](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/TLS):

> The TLS support in PJSIP requires OpenSSL development kit (headers and
>   libs) to be installed.

So PJSIP could offer anything that OpenSSL offers. OpenSSL 1.0.1 offers TLS 1.2. OpenSSL 1.0.0 and below does not (see the [CHANGE LOG](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html), and note TLS 1.2 support was added between 1.0.0 and 1.0.1). Since you are working on Android, you likely have OpenSSL 0.9.8. That means TLS 1.2 is probably not available to you using Android's version of OpenSSL.

If you want the ChaCha/Poly cipher suites, then you need OpenSSL 1.0.2. see [ChaCha20/Poly1305 in OpenSSL?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mailing.openssl.users/ruXkkGlPbCI/cuFgf3rqsScJ) on the OpenSSL mailing list.

Your mileage may vary when you start inter-operating with other SIP components or if you are using a SIP proxy.

Comment: Thanks @jww again! The version in Android is 1.0.1.